# it is possible for one App in android to have more than 100 java files?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

Im new to android development, thus I have this question in mind because Im planning to make an app for something that is lets say similar to A book for example. Lets say I have a book of 100 pages, assuming that the book has 60 chapters, each chapter has its own words and audio. Do I have to have a java file for each chapter? means I will have more than 60 java files in app? Does this make sense?

Thanks

Comment: If it's purely words, you don't want to store them in java files. You'd store them in another text data format file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is possible for one App in android to have more than 100 java files?

Yes.

> Do I have to have a java file for each chapter?

No.

---

I suggest thinking about your code and data separately. Write your code to display any chapter (data). Then your same code will be able to handle any number of chapters that you (or someone else!) write.

Start simple. If your audio and text are tied at the verse level, then build your code to display the one verse and its audio. You can store these as separate files and load based on the filenames. Then build a list of filenames for the verse-audio file pairs and allow switching between them. Then add on another layer for chapters.

Comment: +1 to this. The text/audio should be stored in either res/raw or assets and then loaded by a single Java class that serves as just a container for the text/audio.

Comment: Okay. I have understood that I could use text files and audio files then make one java code to handle them, but then how to distinguish between different chapters? each chapter should have its own java file right?

Comment: Just a straight forward question, lets say if I have made that code that read the text files and also add the audio reproduce, providing that I have 60 chapters, how many java file you think my app should have?

Comment: I would expect your app to have no more than a few Java classes. One way that you could accomplish what you're trying to do is to structure your books/chapters/pages into XML or JSON documents. So your app would load books.xml to display all of the books, user taps on a book, and behind the scenes a chapter/page is loaded by name/identifier. No need to have multiple Activities in this case since all chapters and pages will contain the same properties. Then you'd only need to figure out how to store a user's progress (SharedPreferences maybe).

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/bjenning04/9c60f0000e6cd2e48a60d40b586c234a. Another possibility is to store your data in a SQLite database, but that may be overkill.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, can I also store audio data in the XML ? how to relate each audio file to the page?

Comment: To be more specific, my app deals with poem, so each chapter has its own poem, when clicking on each verse, it should play its audio, one chapter may have more than 30 verses, they are all written in text files, how to organise such thing?